# Pregmatch html attribute with a json content

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I am trying to get the contents of an html tag attribute but somehow I am failing to get all of the contents:

**Example html**

```
 // clipped for brevity
 <a href="someurl/somemore" data-custom="{"foo": 0, "bar": "string"}">
 // some more html
```

Now I want to get all the contents of the json object that is oddly using double quotes. For that reason I tried to get first the value of the `data` attribute and parse the json later.

I did:

```
preg_match('/< *a[^>]*data-custom *= *["\']?([^"\']*)/i', $re, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

where `$re` is the html shown above. But I am getting this:

```
array(2) {
   [0]=> string(39) "<a href="someurl/somemore" data-vote="{"
   [1]=> string(1) "{"
```

What do you think? Also if you happen to know a direct way to extract the json values in a faster way, how would you do it?

Comment: what about preg_match("/data-custom=\"(.?)\"/iSu", $re, $matches);

Comment: nah, still the same.

Comment: Then: preg_match("/data-custom=(.?)/iSu", $re, $matches); after it trim($matches[1], '"');

Comment: @bksi, try before you post. Neither of those work. However, if you replace the `?` with `*` they do, somewhat

Comment: It is inadvisable to parse HTML with regex.  Try a DOM parser.

Comment: @ColinvH it is pretty hard to get the attribute value of a hypenated attribute.

Comment: @JoeySalacHipolito Any DOM parser that can't handle hyphens is pretty broken.  What parsers have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can try something like below:

```
$html = '<a href="someurl/somemore" data-custom="{"foo": 0, "bar": "string"}" class="btn">Vote</a>';
preg_match('~\{\s*(.*?)\s*\}~', $html, $m);
$json = $m[0];
print $json;
```

**Output:**

```
{"foo": 0, "bar": "string"}
```

[**Regex Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/wJ2gQ6/2)

Comment: The problem with this if the anchor tag has more attributes after it like so: `class="btn">Vote</a>'` and it'll result to:

`{"foo": 0, "bar": "string"} class="btn">text</a`

Comment: Updated regex, Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 1):

This works, unless your link has much more to it...

```
$str = '<a href="someurl/somemore" data-custom="{"foo": 0, "bar": "string"}">';
preg_match('/< *a[^>]*data-custom=(.*)>/i', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(69) "<a href="someurl/somemore" data-custom="{"foo": 0, "bar": "string"}">"
  [1]=>
  string(29) ""{"foo": 0, "bar": "string"}""
}
```